# Problem using Grafana with BigQuery datasource

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana, dashboard

The only way I found to visualize BigQuery data with Grafana, it was using this datasource plugin available from https://github.com/doitintl/bigquery-grafana

But doesn't work me fine.

I'm not able to draw nothing with sense.

I only would like know the cost by project in the period selected, that's possible?

Can you help me please?

For example this query

```
SELECT
  CAST (`service`.`description`AS String ) AS metric,
  ROUND(SUM(cost),2) as total_cost,
  project.name
FROM `xxxx`
WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME >= '2019-09-01 00:00:00' AND _PARTITIONTIME < '2019-09-11 23:59:59'
GROUP BY metric, project.name
ORDER BY total_cost DESC
```

I recieve this error in grafana, when I put the Format as "table"

```
No field name specified to use for x-axis, check your axes settings
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Which column is your x-axis in mind? Name (project.name), metric or total_cost? It feels more natural to show such data as a bar chart.

Comment: I would like project.name in x-axis. But I don't know solve that error. If it works with bar chart could you say me what is your query? because I neither didn't get it work with bar-chart. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Which visualization did you choose? If you choose table what kind of table transform did you choose?
In most cases, you will nee a time column in your query.

Something along the lines of:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
 TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(`bill_datetime`), 86400) * 86400),
  CAST (`description`AS String ) AS metric,
  sum(`cost`) AS cost
FROM `project.dataset.account_billing_log`
WHERE
  `bill_datetime` BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (1411102892775) AND TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (1568869292775) AND _PARTITIONTIME >= '2014-09-19 08:01:32' AND _PARTITIONTIME < '2019-09-19 08:01:32'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
  LIMIT 960
```

Comment: If I put these lines I receive this error
InvalidQuery: Syntax Error: Unexpected keyword LIMIT at [13:3]

If I delete LIMIT then I receive this one

InvalidQuery: Unrecognize name bill_datetime at [8:3]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you replace `project.dataset.account_billing_log` with your project and data set?
What's the error?

Comment: Yes, I replaced, the error is that I put before, if I put LIMIT is one error, and if I delete LIMIT I receive another "InvalidQuery: Unrecognize name bill_datetime at [8:3]"

Comment: Can you share the table schema?

Comment: Yes, this one: https://privatebin.net/?e072afe480c8ae4d#Ac2YFLWY5v5B6rMDCZV5Yt4LEk976VfXacVbFVY5Qoxc

Comment: #standardSQL
SELECT
 TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(`bill_datetime`), 86400) * 86400),
  CAST (`description`AS String ) AS metric,
  sum(`cost`) AS cost,account_name
FROM `projetc.dataset..account_billing_log`
WHERE
  `bill_datetime` BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (1411102892775) AND TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (1568869292775) AND _PARTITIONTIME >= '2014-09-19 08:01:32' AND _PARTITIONTIME < '2019-09-19 08:01:32'
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
  LIMIT 960

Comment: Did you try to use the query builder?